# mysql join or concat query from two table to get month wise registration

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I have two tables reg_dealer and claim_data .

```
SELECT YEAR(claim_dt) AS `Year`, 
       MONTHNAME(claim_dt) AS `Month`, 
       COUNT(distinct `uniquecode`) AS `No of Reg` 
FROM claim_data
WHERE YEAR(claim_dt) = '2016' 
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month` 
ORDER BY MONTH(claim_dt) DESC


SELECT YEAR(reg_date) AS `Year`, 
       MONTHNAME(reg_date) AS `Month`, 
       COUNT(*) AS `No of Reg`
FROM reg_dealer 
WHERE YEAR(reg_date) = '2016' 
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month` 
ORDER BY MONTH(reg_date)  DESC
```

i am getting month wise result from both table in same format.

```
Year----------Month----------No_of_Reg
2016          March           150
2016          February        125
2016          Janurary         75
```

and i want registration and claim in a one go

```
Year----------Month----------No_of_Reg---------No_of_claims
2016          March           150                350
2016          February        125                250
2016          Janurary         75                150
```

also want to get the unique claimants

please help

Comment: Join the two queries on the year and month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the queries.

```
SELECT t1.Year, t1.Month, `No of Reg`, `No of Claims`
FROM (SELECT YEAR(claim_dt) AS `Year`, MONTHNAME(claim_dt) AS `Month`, MONTH(claim_dt) AS MonthNum, COUNT(distinct `uniquecode`) AS `No of Claims` 
        FROM claim_data 
        WHERE YEAR(claim_dt) = '2016' GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(reg_date) AS `Year`, MONTH(claim_dt) AS MonthNum, COUNT(*) AS `No of Reg` 
        FROM reg_dealer 
        WHERE YEAR(reg_date) = '2016' 
        GROUP BY `Year`, `MonthNum`) AS t2
    ON t1.Year = t2.Year AND t1.MonthNum = t2.MonthNum
ORDER BY t1.Year, t1.MonthNum DESC
```

Comment: thank for the answer , but query not executed, getting error Unknown column 't2.Month' in 'on clause' and i replace t2.month to t2.MonthNum but no result

Comment: Sorry, meant to change that to `MonthNum`.

Comment: but sir query got the message Your SQL query has been executed successfully (Query took 0.0126 sec) but no result

Comment: There will only be results for months that have both claims and registrations.

Comment: works now! script is working but no of claim output is not exactly like my query is written

Comment: How is it different?

Comment: If you need to get months that aren't in both tables, you need a full outer join. MySQL doesn't have this operation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql for workarounds.